# Want to fetch class name using php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, classname

I am facing some problem to get the class name of a div.
For example my html is like that...

```
<div class="rating-static rating-48 "></div>
<div class="rating-static rating-40 "></div>
```

I need to get the value ,for example  48 
Don't know if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :-

```
$('div.rating-static').each(function(){
  var value = $(this).attr('class').split('-')[2];
  alert(value);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8r16my1/1/)

OR

```
$('div.rating-static').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr('class').substring($(this).attr('class').lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
    alert(value);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8r16my1/2/)

Comment: @soundhiraraj..you are mistaken ... just check the fiddle link.

Comment: i checked sir,it comes last alert as undefined

Comment: thanks a lot Kartikeya .it is working :),but is it possible to use the class name,i mean 'rating-static' because in this html there are some other div.

Comment: @user2578819..yes .. as you can see in my code i have used `$('div.rating-static')` as selector which will select only `div's` with class name `rating-static`